# Rewrite urls php/mysql page with htaccess apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a search form to search for a health institution in a city.
when I display the results I have this URL for example :
`search.php?city=mycity&speciality=cardiology`

I would like to rewrite this URL like this: `health-institution-cardiology-mycity`

I set up an `.htaccess` rule like this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule health-entity-([a-zA-Z\-]+)-([a-zA-Z\-]+) search.php?city=$2&speciality=$1
```

It doesn't work, however, I applied this rule to another type of URL and it works

is there any issue with the code?
do I need to add something?

Comment: You wrote `health-entity` in your rule, but `health-institution` in your example URL

Comment: thanks Joffrey, an error from my side, it's health-institution in both cases, the problem remains the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^health-institution-([a-z]+)-([a-z]+)/?$ search.php?city=$2&speciality=$1 [NC,L]
```

Note: The NC (No Case) at the end makes the rurl case insensitive.

Comment: thank you @josé , it works :)

I have another problem:

when I make a link for example: health-institution-cardiology-mycity, the url rewrite works, it redirects to the right content

but when I do a search through the search form it displays the unrewritten url search.php?city=mycity&speciality=cardiology, how can I fix that so i get the rewritten url?

Comment: I guess that you've got an HTML form with method="get" and action="search.php", so it works as usually: sending params by URL. You need to prevent your form to work as usually, and, instead of be sent, just redirect to the friendly URL, using the format you want. You can make a Javascript function that will be invoked on form submit, or on button click. In that function, you build the URL as you want, taking the values from the inputs, and redirect (change location) to that URL. Don't forget to return false on submit form. And, hey, you can vote my anwser up and accept it if worked ;)

Comment: I mean, nothing to do in .htaccess, you just need to build your friendly URLs inside your webpage.

Comment: thank you José, your explanation is clear, I'll try to implement this solution